# Graceful way to handle lookup errors in excel 2011 for mac

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

I would like to do a `vlookup`, and if the `vlookup` fails, return the just the contents of the source.

Example:

```
=vlookup(target,Range,column,FALSE)
```

returns `#N/A` I want it to return target.

Right now I can do this with the `ISNA` function, but it's clunky:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B14,$CA$2:$CJ$68,5)),B14,VLOOKUP(B14,$CA$2:$CJ$68,5))
```

This is clunky, and this is only a simple lookup. Is there a smoother way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use excel in Windows, but I think solution is the same, use `iferror` instead of `isna`:
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B14,$CA$2:$CJ$68,5),B14)`